# Duplicate rows when merging unequal panel data

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rstudio

I need to merge two panel datasets, which are of different size. These datasets are both geo-referenced by coordinate-columns. The units in one of the datasets are grid-cells, which together cover the whole world. The coordinates of this dataset refer to the centroid of the grid-cells. The other dataset has data on conflicts, with coordinates for where the conflicts took place.

However, when I try to merge these datasets by coordinates, conflict-events are not placed correctly by year, which messes up everything. I believe that I can "fix" this by creating duplicate rows where there are multiple conflict-events per grid-cell-year, however I have no idea how to this.

```
Dataset1 (Grid-cell structure)
X       gid       row       col       xcoord       ycoord       imr_mean       year   
100      1         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1990 
101      2         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1992
102      3         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1991
103      4         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1993
104      5         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1994
105      6         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        2000
106      7         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        2001
107      8         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1998
108      9         195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1999
109      10        195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1996
110      11        195      197       -81.75        7.25         200.00        1995

Dataset 2 (Conflict events)
X       eventid       gwno       xcoord       ycoord       ndeath       year
32      400032         40         24.01       -81.84         41         1994 
300     410041         41         18.53       -72.33         5          1990
302     410043         41         19.66       -72.55         8          1990
308     410049         41         18.43       -72.86         13         1990
313     410054         41         18.53       -72.33         14         1990
323     410062         41         18.53       -72.33         7          1990
325     410064         41         18.97       -74.26         12         1991
326     410065         41         18.53       -72.33         13         1991
424     410151         41         18.53       -72.33         5          1993
471     410205         41         18.29       -73.82         30         1994
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
I've attempted different codes, i'll write some examples.

```
test <- merge(ds1, ds2, by.x = "xcoord", by.y = "ycoord") 
test <- geo_join(ds1, ds2, by = c("xcoord", "ycoord"), max_dist = 27.5, unit = "km", mode = "full"
test <- geo_full_join(ds1, ds2, by = c(ds1$xcoord, ds2$xcoord), method = "haversine", unit = "km", max_dist = 27.5, distance_col = NULL)
```

The geo_joins seem to place the events correctly by coordinates, but not by year. My desired output should have placed the events correctly by both year and area. For instance, imagine that one of the rows in ds1 is New York. In 1991 there are three events in ds2 which are placed within the NYC-cell. As it is now, only one of these events will be merged correctly, that is both by coordinates and year. The others will be misplaced by year because there is only one cell-year-observation per year. I want each conflict event to be a seperate row. I believe, with my admittedly limited knowledge, that this can be fixed by duplicating the rows in DS1 where there are multiple events in DS2 happening in the same cell-year, however I really struggle to find a way to do this.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using when attempting to merge these datasets

Comment: I've edited the post, @Greg

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your desired output, but below is an example of using `merge` to merge two data frames

```
dfout <- merge(df1,df2,all = T)
```

such that

```
> dfout
     X xcoord ycoord year gid row col imr_mean eventid gwno ndeath
1   32  24.01 -81.84 1994  NA  NA  NA       NA  400032   40     41
2  100 -81.75   7.25 1990   1 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
3  101 -81.75   7.25 1992   2 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
4  102 -81.75   7.25 1991   3 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
5  103 -81.75   7.25 1993   4 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
6  104 -81.75   7.25 1994   5 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
7  105 -81.75   7.25 2000   6 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
8  106 -81.75   7.25 2001   7 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
9  107 -81.75   7.25 1998   8 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
10 108 -81.75   7.25 1999   9 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
11 109 -81.75   7.25 1996  10 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
12 110 -81.75   7.25 1995  11 195 197      200      NA   NA     NA
13 300  18.53 -72.33 1990  NA  NA  NA       NA  410041   41      5
14 302  19.66 -72.55 1990  NA  NA  NA       NA  410043   41      8
15 308  18.43 -72.86 1990  NA  NA  NA       NA  410049   41     13
16 313  18.53 -72.33 1990  NA  NA  NA       NA  410054   41     14
17 323  18.53 -72.33 1990  NA  NA  NA       NA  410062   41      7
18 325  18.97 -74.26 1991  NA  NA  NA       NA  410064   41     12
19 326  18.53 -72.33 1991  NA  NA  NA       NA  410065   41     13
20 424  18.53 -72.33 1993  NA  NA  NA       NA  410151   41      5
21 471  18.29 -73.82 1994  NA  NA  NA       NA  410205   41     30
```